# Asymptotic density of abundant numbers

Tags: number-theory

Let $A(n)$ represent the number of abundant numbers less than or equal to $n$. While working through a number theory exercise, I wrote a C++ program to calculate $\sigma(n)$ for all $1 \leq n \leq 10^5$, and to tally whether they were abundant, deficient, or perfect. To make a long story short, $\frac{A(10^5)}{10^5} = 0.24795$. It seems remarkably close to $\frac{1}{4}$. Does $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{A(n)}{n} = \frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: 'Asymptotic density
As a consequence of the closure under multiplication by arbitrary positive integers, the even abundant numbers are of positive density. In particular, their lower density is at least 0.2453 and their upper density is at most 0.2460."  https://oeis.org/wiki/Even_abundant_numbers#:~:text=number%20is%20abundant.-,Asymptotic%20density,density%20is%20at%20most%200.2460.

Comment: Thank you, but that's only the even ones. What about the odd ones?

Comment: https://digitalcommons.cwu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1059&context=math Davenport showed in 1933 that the density of the abundant numbers exists. Kobayashi showed in 2010 that its value is between 0.2476171 and 0.2476475.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

As far as I know the state of the art is still [Kobayashi's dissertation](https://collections.dartmouth.edu/archive/object/dcdis/dcdis-kobayashim2010), which asserts that the natural density of the abundant numbers satisfies $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{A(n)}{n} \in [0.2476171,0.2476475] .$$

Comment: Deléglise found an upper bound of $0.2480$ for the density in 1998, in particular establishing that the limit is not $\frac{1}{4}$.